# tortoisehg branch colors won't change

Tags: tortoisehg

I'm trying to change the branch colors in TortoiseHg. I have read in the documentation how to, but the color still will not change. The colors hg chose are the same color, so I'd like to change it to something else. This is what I have in the branch color field, but it doesn't seem to effect the repo. I tried this in both global and repo settings

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To set branch color do the following:

1. File --> Settings
2. In "Branch Colors": enter color in the following format:
   [branch1 name]:#[Hex Code] [branch2 name]: #[Hex Code] 
   Example: default:#FF0000 branch1Name:#f42233
3. Ok --> **Restart tortoisehg**